# Viewing Windows SCM's .EVM files

Tags: windows, logging, services, logfiles

I have developed some windows services and noticed that at some point in time, the Windows service manager will stop and resume my service without notifying anything.

I know Windows SCM logs are located at `%windir%\system32\LogFiles\Scm` but I have not been able to know of any program that can interpret these files so I can view the SCM's Behaviour on this matter (these are binary files).

EDIT:

I found out that they can be viewed in the Event Viewer under Windows Registry > System.